# Error: /dev/hugepages does not exist

Tags: mountpoint

Today, when I ran DPDK on Ubuntu, I got this error:

```
$ sudo mount -t hugetlbfs -o pagesize=1G none /dev/hugepages
mount: mount point /dev/hugepages does not exist
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Does the mount point exist?

Comment: Better question, why are you trying to create a dev file in this manner?

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I want to install DPDK in OVS (Open vswitch).  OVS needs a system with 1GB hugepages support.
You can see in this link.
http://openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/INSTALL.DPDK.md.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using DPDK on ubuntu with low latency kernel (3.16.0-33-lowlatency #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT). I used the quick start link below to configure it and it works okay for me.

http://dpdk.org/doc/quick-start

For 1G huge pages support, did you set the kernel parameters `"default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=4"` in `/boot/grub/grub.conf` file?

https://embedded.communities.intel.com/thread/6681

But I haven't tried this though.

Answer (score 0):

for Ubuntu 16.04 the init scripts in the packaging can help you to get this persistent and taken care of the mountpoints.

Essentially you can set
NR_2M_PAGES=4096
or
NR_1G_PAGES=8
The scripts will try to allocate them early (not as early as the kernel command line solution) and ensure that some dpdk compatible hugepage mountpoints are available.

See more at:
https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/serverguide/DPDK.html#dpdk-config-hp

Answer (score 0):

In order to use 1GB huge pages for DPDK please follow the steps as

1. edit the /etc/default/grub as grub default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=1 (for 1GB 1 Huge page)
2. update the grub settings via update-grub tool.
3. to mount the huge page to desired `mkdir /dev/huge1G; mount -t hugetlbfs -o pagesize=1G none /dev/huge1G`
4. Start DPDK application with rte_eal_init args as --huge-dir=/dev/huge1G

Note: these can be performed on a Linux Kernel which has enabled Huge pages. To check if huge pages are built execute grep -nr HUGE /boot/config*

```
CONFIG_HUGETLBFS=y
CONFIG_HUGETLB_PAGE=y
```